# minimize a simple constrained linear function

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization, linear-programming

I'm trying to optimize:

$\min\limits_{w}\ \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} w_ia_i\ $ subject to, $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} w_i=1,\ w_i \in [0,1]\  \forall i$.

Where it is known that all $a_i \geq 0$.

---

I can work out that if this was a $\max$ problem instead of a $\min$ problem, the solution would be $w_i=\frac{a_i}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i}$.

I'm trying to figure out how to work out the solution for a $\min$ problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $m=\min(a_1,...,a_n)$ and let $M=\max(a_1,...,a_n)$.

The set of realizable values for a convex combination of $a_1,...,a_n$ is the set of numbers between $m$ and $M$ inclusive.

Thus the minimum possible value is $m$, which can be achieved by letting $w_i=1$ for some $i$ such that $a_i=m$ and letting $w_j=0$ if $j\ne i$.

Similarly, the maximum possible value is $M$, which can be achieved by letting $w_i=1$ for some $i$ such that $a_i=M$ and letting $w_j=0$ if $j\ne i$.

Answer (score 1):

To get the min just put all the weights on the minimum $a_i$, so if $i^* \in \{i : a_i \leq a_j \forall j=1,\cdots,n\}$, then $w_{i^*} = 1$ and $w_{i}=0$ for all $i\neq i^*$ is a solution.

If the set $I = \{i : a_i \leq a_j ~\forall j=1,\cdots,n\} = \{i^*_1, \cdots, i^*_k \}$ has more the one element, then any convex combination of $w_{i^*_1}, \cdots, w_{i^*_k}$ with $w_i=0$ for all $i\not\in I$ is also a solution, and it covers all the solutions.